# Programming Error when trying to merge multiple pandas data frames into postgresql database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database of sql tables to store at a central database location.

I am using this command to cycle through a directory of 1300 csv files and append to a postgresql database. The source will list the file name without the ".csv" so that I can bring it back out when I need it.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2
import time
import os

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user@127.0.0.1',isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')

for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    file_path = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    column = filename[:-4]
    column = column.lower()
    pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0).assign(Source=column).to_sql('test', if_exists='append', con=engine)
```

I try the following command but I keep running into the following error after opening the 2nd file.

```
UndefinedColumn                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/envs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1255                 if not evt_handled:
-> 1256                     self.dialect.do_executemany(
   1257                         cursor, statement, parameters, context

~/miniconda3/envs/scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    872         if self.executemany_mode is EXECUTEMANY_DEFAULT:
--> 873             cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
    874             return

UndefinedColumn: column "HSJSJKSAAISKD" of relation "test" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test ("DATE", "HSJSJKSAAISKD", "Source") VALUE...
                                 ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5f59a73397c3> in <module>
      7     column = column.lower()
      8     print(column)
----> 9     pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0).assign(Source=column).to_sql('test', if_exists='append', con=engine)
.....
.....
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "HSJSJKSAAISKD" of relation "test" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test ("DATE", "HSJSJKSAAISKD", "Source") VALUE...
```

Comment: Can you check the file content to see where this column `HSJSJKSAAISKD` is coming from?

Comment: its the name of my csv file

Comment: and also the name of the column after the Date column. each csv file is Date followed by a unique ID, which is also the name of the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says the column is not present in the table. Before writing it to the database, can you print your data frame and check whether all the columns present in your data frame are matched with the database table

Comment: each column is unique. does the column name have to be the same?

Comment: is it possible to create a new table for each csv file like this?

Comment: column names must be same if you are writing to the same table

Comment: I understand, is there a way to create a new table with a unique name each time I access a new csv file?

Comment: yeah you can create new table, all you have to do is change the name of the table for each loop

Comment: if you have 1300 csv files, then it will create 1300 tables. are you sure you want to create those many tables

Comment: is there a way to create a new column each time instead of a new row ? so I can see a new column with a unique id each time?, can 1300 tables be merged quickly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223316/discussion-between-sandeep-patil-and-anarchy).